# Android activity won't fill WVGA screen

Tags: android, layout, screen

I'm developing an Activity with a simple LinearLayout with a button. When I try the activity on my hardware (WVGA 480x800 screen) the activity only fills the standard size (480x320) while the OS itself fills the whole screen.

What could be the issue.

Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FFF"                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">  
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01"                          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have to specify in the manifest file that you want to allow the application to scale to the size of a larger screen.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#attrs for more info.

There is a part about `<supports-screens>` attribute in the manifest that might have what you are looking for.

Comment: You where right! Specifying the Screen Size in the manifest file resolved my issue thanks!!!!

Mat